# Find $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{M-1} \sin\left(\frac{j\pi}{M}\right)\frac{j}{M}\left(1-\frac{j}{M}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

I have been tasked to show $$\boxed{\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{M-1} \sin\left(\frac{j\pi}{M}\right)\frac{j}{M}\left(1-\frac{j}{M}\right)=\frac{1}{4M^2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{M}\right)\csc^4\left(\frac{\pi}{2M}\right)}$$

I think I *could* do this with a mess of complex exponentials ($\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{M-1}\exp\left(\frac{i\pi xj}{M}\right)$ evaluated at 1) and differentiating the geometric series sum twice but that seems **very** messy. I was wondering if there was an easier way.

**If not, is there an easy way to instead find this sum to leading order in M**?

Comment: Your sum is a factor of $1/M$ from being a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 \sin(\pi x) x(1-x) dx = 4/\pi^3$ so, to leading order in $M,$ your sum is $4M/\pi^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still manageable. Note
$$f(x)= \sum_{j=1}^{M-1}e^{i\frac{\pi xj}{M}}
=\frac{e^{i\frac{\pi x}{M}}-e^{i\pi x}}{1-e^{i\frac{\pi x}{M}} }
$$
$$f’(x)= i \sum_{j=1}^{M-1}e^{i\frac{\pi xj}{M}}\frac{\pi j}M,\>\>\>
f’’(x)= -\sum_{j=1}^{M-1}e^{i\frac{\pi xj}{M}}\frac{\pi^2j^2}{M^2}
$$
Then
\begin{align}
&\sum_{j=1}^{M-1} \sin\frac{j\pi x}{M}\left(1-\frac{j}{M}\right)\frac{j}{M}\\
= &Im \left(\frac1{i\pi}f’(x)+\frac1{\pi^2}f’’(x)\right)\\
= &\frac{d}{dx}Im \left(\frac1{i\pi}f(x)+\frac1{\pi^2}f’(x)\right)\\
=& \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac1{2\pi}-\frac1{2\pi M}\sin^2\frac{\pi x}2 \csc^2\frac{\pi x}{2M} \right)\\
= &\frac1{4M^2}\left(2\sin^2\frac{\pi x}2\cot\frac{\pi x}{2M}-M\sin\pi x\right) \csc^2\frac{\pi x}{2M} 
\end{align}
Set $x=1$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^{M-1} \sin\frac{j\pi}{M}\left(1-\frac{j}{M}\right)\frac{j}{M}= \frac1{2M^2}\cot\frac{\pi x}{2M} \csc^2\frac{\pi x}{2M} 
= \frac{1}{4M^2}\sin\frac{\pi}{M}\csc^4\frac{\pi}{2M}
\end{align}

Comment: This is the easiest way to do this, but unfortunately OP is looking for another way (whatever that might be)

Comment: Ahh that's fine, I just overcomplicated it when I tried, this works fine, thanks ;)